# A Riddle With a Transverse Twitch

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> Stand in waiting, patchwork thing.
>   One addressed may comfort bring.
>   Vision's ball. Soft layering.
>   Crooked pipe form covering.
>   Steamy drink: hive's fashioning?

The answer is a single English word.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is

> QUILT

because in each line,

> the first half gives a single **letter** of the solution and the second half **describes** the solution.

*Stand in waiting, patchwork thing.*

> "Stand in waiting" = queue or **Q**. Second half: patchwork quilt.

*One addressed may comfort bring.*

> "One addressed" = you or **U**. Second half: a quilt brings comfort.

*Vision's ball. Soft layering.*

> "Vision's ball" = eye or **I**. Second half: a quilt forms a soft layer.

*Crooked pipe form covering.*

> "Crooked pipe" = **L**. Second half: a quilt is a cover.

*Steamy drink: hive's fashioning?*

> "Steamy drink" = tea or **T**. <strike>Not sure about "hive's fashioning" - it sounds rather like bee or **B**.</strike> [Apparently](http://warre.biobees.com/quilt.htm) a quilt is something used for beehives.
>  OP: I intended the last line as a reference to quilting bees. The title translates to "a cross tic" to hint at the acrostic nature of this riddle.

Comment: What would you call a group that fashioned your answer?

Comment: @HughMeyers A den of riddlers?

Comment: I was thinking "dhvygvat orr" but close enough for a tick. There's a little wordplay in the title as well. :-)